# How to create, listen and trigger custom event in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, event-handling, jquery-events

I need to create global custom event, to be able listen and trigger it. 
In **jQuery** I would do it like that:

```
$(document).on('myCustomEvent', function(){
    console.log("myCustomEvent triggered");
})

$(document).trigger('myCustomEvent');
```

---

**What for?**

I need to create communication between not related components.

---

**Question:**

How to **listen** and **trigger** global custom **events** in **ReactJS**?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add listeners you can still do this with jQuery. Start listening in the `componentDidMount` and stop listening in `componentWillUnmount` see [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html). If it wants to be global (visible to child components), you can do this in the topmost component and propagate down with props.